# What Was With that Med School?

Tags: production, realism, flatliners-1990

I just got done watching [Flatliners](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099582/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm). What was with that medical school? It looked like it was falling apart. Then the main building they were performing the experiment in was under major reconstruction. The apartments/dorms looked like a rough neighborhood.

I’d think a medical school would look far more prestigious than what that film depicted.

Comment: (Removed thread).  I think its clear enough he means Flatliners 1990 with Kevin Bacon, William Baldwin and Julia Roberts.

Comment: I didn't spend six years in Evil Medical School to be called "Mister", thank you very much.

Comment: "Then the main building they were performing the experiment in was under major reconstruction." This seems to be the answer. IT WAS UNDER RECONSTRUCTION. You have to tear down to rebuild.

Comment: Yes but it looked like a museum........with pieces of art being RESTORED. So my point is.........a med school.......in an art museum???!!

Comment: @TylerDurden Okay, Dr. Evil. It was a mini-mistake.

Comment: I mean I suppose I could allude to the director/writers making a symbolic gesture towards the point of the story.........but that’s about all I could think of that makes sense

Comment: This is your take-away about unbelievable stuff in the movie? The condition of the school? Not ALL the other stuff? The movie is a trainwreck of unbelievable rubbish. I get why you asked the question, but everything else seems MORE unbelievable. A school having art and being redone? Least of the story problems to me. In a story of people intentionally dying and then bringing back supernatural crap, renovation is a minor concern. This is the same director as The Lost Boys. Subtlety is not in his bag of tricks.Nor is normal location scouting. **This is the director who added nipples to Batman.**

Comment: I can enjoy the movie, but I have to forgive how deeply flawed it can be. I didn't mean to rant. Sorry. Just a suggestion: take the [Tour](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tour) and get another badge!